# Django passing parameter as a string

Tags: django, python-2.7

My URL, submitted to Django contains a date as a parameter `&s1=2015-04-21`
in my view I send this parameter by the way:

```
if 's1' in request.GET:
    s1 = request.GET['s1'] 
else: 
    s1 = '2015-01-01' 
context_dict = {'page': page, 'lang': lang, 's1': s1}
return render_to_response('..../index.html', context_dict, context)
```

In the template file I try to catch this parameter:

```
var s1 = {{ s1 }};
```

Instead of `2015-04-21`, I got `1990`. How can I change the code to get proper string, not result of calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you set `s1` in your view?

Comment: sure:        if 's1' in request.GET:
            s1 = request.GET['s1']
        else:
            s1 = '2015-01-01'

Comment: please edit the question of putting code in the comments.. It is more readable that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use it in JavaScript. If you want it as a string, you need to quote it:

```
var s1 = "{{s1}}";
```

Otherwise the JavaScript code will see it is a mathematical expression and calculate it.